# Can i just use this library?

Tags: android, calendar, libraries

Sorry if this sounds stupid but i dont normally use seperate libraries in andorid. I wanted to add a calendar to my app however i could not find a way to implement a day view calendar that looked nice. I found this library that looked like it would be useful at the bottom of the github it had a Apache License Version 2.0, i went to read the license but did not understand most of it. My question is do i just need to give credit to the creator of the library or do i need to ask permission (i was planning on making a commercial app if that makes any difference)? Again im not very experienced in using 3rd party libraries so any help would be much appreciated Thank You.

Here is the link to the library on github (the apache license is at the bottom) - https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library, but you must show a link to the library that you used in your app. Usually this info placed in "About" screen

Comment: Like in the additional information section at the bottom? or in the description?

Comment: It does not matter, the main thing that used libraries were mentioned